# C++: static assert that functor's argument is const reference

Tags: c++, c++17, metaprogramming, template-meta-programming

I'm writing a template function in `C++17` which accepts a functor `F` as argument and I want to restrict the passed in functor to have only one constant reference argument, where `T` can be any type.

for example:

```cpp
template <class T> struct my_struct{
    std::vector<T> collection;
    template <class F> std::vector<T> func(F f){
        static_assert(
               // CONDITION HERE!,
               "f's argument is not const reference"
            );

        std::vector<T> ret;

        std::copy_if(
                std::make_move_iterator(this->collection.begin()),
                std::make_move_iterator(this->collection.end()),
                std::inserter(ret, ret.end()),
                f
            );

        return ret;
    }
};
```

Obviously, in case `f` is `[](auto v){return true;}` the resulting vector returned from `func` will have empty elements (because those are moved before adding to resulting container). So, I need to restrict possible input functors to `[](const auto& v){}`.

I have tried something like this:

```cpp
static_assert(
        std::is_invocable_v<F, const T&>,
        "f's argument is not const reference"
    );
```

But then `func([](auto v){})` does not trigger the assertion, because `T` is copyable in my case.
The `func([](auto& v){})` also passes the test, because `auto` can be `const T`.

But I need to limit possible lambdas to be `func([](const auto& v){})`.

Comment: *"`auto` itself can be `const T&`"*  - It can't. It's a value type. It passed the test because the type is copyable. What are you trying to accomplish? Why "by const-ref only" seems like the solution?

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica right, it's because it is copyable. As I said, I'm trying to prevent the argument of the `F` to be moved or modified.

Comment: Sounds like you just need to do an rvalue to lvalue conversion of the thing you pass to the function.  Using `const auto&& lvalue_temp = expression_that_generates_temporary;` and then passing `lvalue_temp` to `f` will make sure it can't be moved or modified.

Comment: Why not simply pass it via `std::as_const`, then? It will trip modifications (not accouning `const_cast`, but we should assume sane functors). You can also make local copies if its not expansive. Let the functor have those.

Comment: I have added more info to the question, with more or less exact code I have. As one can see, I'm using move iterators and `std::copy_if`. This might give more info about what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to achieve it in the following way:

```cpp
template <class T> struct my_struct{
    std::vector<T> collection;

    struct noncopyable_value_type : T{
        noncopyable_value_type(const noncopyable_value_type&) = delete;
        noncopyable_value_type& operator=(const noncopyable_value_type&) = delete;
    };

    template <class F> std::vector<T> func(F f){
        static_assert(
               std::is_invocable_v<F, noncopyable_value_type>,
               "f's argument must be const reference"
            );

        std::vector<T> ret;

        std::copy_if(
                std::make_move_iterator(this->collection.begin()),
                std::make_move_iterator(this->collection.end()),
                std::inserter(ret, ret.end()),
                f
            );

        return ret;
    }
};
```

But still, the problem here is that it only works with generic lambdas.

Answer (score 1):

You might write traits (with its limitations), something like:

```
template <typename Sig> struct callable_traits;

template <typename Ret, typename ...Args>
struct callable_traits<Ret(*)(Args...)>
{
    using args = std::tuple<Args...>;
};
// add specialization for C-ellipsis too

template <typename Ret, class C, typename ...Args>
struct callable_traits<Ret(C::*)(Args...) const>
{
    using args = std::tuple<Args...>;
};
// add specialization for variant with C-ellipsis, cv-qualifier, ref-qualifier

template <class C>
struct callable_traits<C> : callable_traits<&C::operator()>{};
```

Limitation of the traits: doesn't handle templated `operator()` (as for generic lambda), overloaded `operator()`.

And then

```
template <class T> struct my_struct{
    template <class F> void func(F f){
        static_assert(
               std::is_same_v<std::tuple<const T&>, typename callable_traits<F>::args>,
               "f's argument is not const reference"
            );

        // here goes some code which can possibly call f with rvalue
        // reference argument, so I want to avoid situation when the
        // argument object is moved or modified. I don't have control
        // over this code because it an STL algorithm.
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for proposal, this looks like it should work. But, unfortunately, there is a blocker. You mention that this does not work for for generic lambdas, but I would like to be able to use actually generic lambdas, this is crucial as writing exact types might be too difficult, those can be long.

Answer (score 1):

I could be misunderstanding what you're trying to do but, as I read it, you want to accept a callable, then pass some argument to it with a guarantee that the argument cannot be changed (you don't want someone to accept the argument as a non-const l-value reference or an r-value reference. If so, then [std::is_invocable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_invocable) should be enough:

```cpp
#include <type_traits> // for std::is_invocable
#include <functional> // for std::invoke

template <class parameter_t> struct my_struct {
    template <typename callable_t>
    void function(callable_t const &callable) requires (
        std::is_invocable<callable_t, parameter_t const &>::value
    ) {
        // . . .
        std::invoke(callable, parameter_t{});
        // . . .
    }
};
```

Then:

```cpp
int main() {
    my_struct<int>{}.function([](int const&){}); // Fine
    my_struct<int>{}.function([](int){}); // Fine, a copy of the parameter is made when the lambda is invoked.
    my_struct<int>{}.function([](int &){}); // error: no matching member function for call to 'function'
    my_struct<int>{}.function([](int &&){}); // error: no matching member function for call to 'function'
}
```

(You can play around with it [here](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAM1QDsCBlZAQwBtMQBGAFlICsQAJlKtmtUMgCkggELSZpAM6Z2yAnjqVMtdAGFUrAK4BbWkNLb0AGTy1MAORMAjTMSEAGUgAdUiwhtp9I1Mub19/Ohs7R2MXNx4lFUw1AIYCZmICIJMzYWVVdTo0jIIoh2dXDyV0zOyQzmqSspi4rm4ASiVUQ2JkDgByaQBmW2QjLABqSSHdAgBPL0wAfQJiZkJFaexJdwBBYdHxzCmZqkNaFLo2LZ39vYJMYy9RB5PdMeZFRQmvDOZjTAPYgrLYTRSrQxqCbGOZLcHESEEKYAdjkewmGImDyeL2O01mC20/2OLFYoic7BBQ226MxADdUHh0BMzhdCrQIKTyZSkWhaOCpoIAGxc5gUzDtCbETAAR0MeGl3wgt0xqrBBHQIBAeEUS1sDJY4vxovFK1IPz%2BAKBKwmfIF0iFWy1dLYhkwKsxkskqI9aomAHp/RMAHQhkO%2BtXgzXa2gMgDWmE5bG5mHNvzWVtcIJ9yIAIu1pmjdn6MYGw6HgxHvbnbtXC7W9rYkcZ1hyvT7aRiYXCIWp8U2bjnc8HWZcOZIAKxyCe5iBN210cEOgtDgtDGQBoMAMVs7s70Nh8MR/fog7keZH5zHyqnk9nTZX5/zhc3Ex3dnNzAXXjmE1QVCxBBjnTYkgQmHVoWYLBK33bsjz7GYB2pb0n0vNkAhvad73oQUhUfas1w3MtXGIEgQAmWhUEgghkAQWxgGhR44hZK92RZEhbWTLEqLAfpR3ZXiIzg3sCBPUTkKHNDr0nLC5xwh1lxQgiX2I4hSLcCiqJbGi6PERjYlcFj0LodjiE4sluImXj%2BICQS9mrfpOlYEB%2BgnfpSDMfp3Hc1AXN0eR5DBbpejxQQhkEdyCBc7z2k6ICoMqCBOjjEAJ3cYNOCGIZ3E4ZFuE4IUAE4hQADncXhnP6bh3OMLh3E8TzvNIXz%2BncxQQE8KKvMc0g4FgGBEBQVAnjwdgyAoTlhq8UbKg%2BcQVgRWg41IKhRqBdqICcaL3KcWwMjmFzOHctBjABegAHlaFYA7utILAW3EdhtruhVknUOlMHa27MAAD2SQwHmepsVGe1g8CcNZiDmfQsEOyLiDwWr%2BiOzoaHoJg2A4BIBAaURxBQALZBEcH2sgTpUC8dkvoAWnOoYJmpqNplzKRZHkQRmDapIxy0HQ6jMBpLGaCp4jCPx2X50IfHFgJhYM0X8je1IaiyAwclCRWx2KTI5daBpwRKSX9ZV3XKk4TpFGCvohCcly3I856Wp%2BkqhWpoVuFtPGGIgCElslCBcEIDjhmECZ9BGsbBSGc2w8JmRIu22LSHirA3CS0gUu4QrgxdoqSsECcSuy6PCuREQXOq0harSh3bpatqOtILqYt6gaICQboCC8AHyEoE7prG0JMHwIg3GENHGFJLHeAAdzWLw4dt1z3ManyXOGTgJhnwgEAmZ3Xfdz2xG93243aBPuqTlPEqXyvq4ax2XIbzrE%2BSkAs5zoU84Lov3BLsvKpDBXo/VqTdX7l36BFWuTV65gMvp0D6xA/CaG4EAA%3D%3D))

A possible problem is that this method does allow a copy to be made, but if the main goal is to protect the variable you hold from changes this should be good enough.

P. S. I know I used c++20 `requires` clause as a way of future-proofing the answer, but it should be trivial to convert it to `if constexpr`, `static_assert` or any other way you prefer.

Comment: unfortunately, this does not work for me. See the original updated description.